# I can't access the internet when Ubuntu updating

Tags: 12.04, internet, software-updater

My question is, why Ubuntu can't access the Internet when updating ? Once a week my Ubuntu starts the software update but when it starts my Internet connection stay so slow or I can't access the website. Thanks.

Comment: It'll depend on your internet bandwidth, not an issue with Ubuntu, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the bandwidth used by apt-get.

Open a terminal and run this command:

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download`

Then paste and save the following (this will limit downloads to 30 KB/s; adjust if needed):

```
Acquire
{
  Queue-mode "access";
  http
  {
    Dl-Limit "30";
  };
};
```

Source: http://chrisjrob.com/2011/03/31/limiting-the-bandwidth-usage-of-apt-get-and-wget/